# lstlisting long line wrapping

Tags: listings, ieeetran, python, wrap, line

[image]I would like to wrap "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac59e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824" into the frame of lstlisting.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  frame=single,
  extendedchars=true,             
  language=Python,                 
  numbers=left,    
  numberstyle=\tiny,               
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=1,                   
  tabsize=2,                       
  title=\lstname,                   
  belowskip=-1em,
  aboveskip=1em,
  belowcaptionskip=0em,
  columns=fullflexible,
  linewidth=8.7cm,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{black}\hookrightarrow\space}},
  literate={,}{,}1
  }
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
block = {
    'previous_hash': "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac59e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried literate={\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{-}}
however, the line still overpass through the frame :(

Comment: Actually, I just split the line with space and it is ok. Thank you all!